# How to call javascript function from PowerBI report?

Tags: javascript, html, css, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have created a custom column that is supposed to have a hyperlink like this:

[image]

And the output is:

[image]

When I inspect this in the browser it shows as text (not html). Here's a screenshot:

[image]

I want to call `comment()` function in javascript. Is it possible?

Comment: Wew, I would hope this is not possible, or this would lead to a pretty serious injection vulnerability AFAICT.

Comment: Is there any idea to achieve  my scenario. in ssrs reports we can call js function, i dont know why power bi not supporting it.